# Internal array representation in v8/node.js

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management, v8

I wrote a small memory benchmark for node.js: http://pastebin.com/KfZ4Ucn4

It measures memory usage using `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed` for 3 cases:

1. Array of objects with 10 properties, different property names for each element
2. Array of objects with 10 properties, same property names
3. Array of objects with 10 properties, same property names, represented as an object of arrays

The overhead turns out to be 1300 bytes for Case 1, 300 bytes for Case 2 and 150 bytes for Case 3. Also only Case 1 garbage collects, while in latter cases memory usage doesn't go down.

Is there any explanation or documentation for these effects? I'm trying to optimize memory usage for an array of objects of objects, something like

```
[ {
     foo : { bar : 1, baz : 2 }
  ,  bar : { bar : 2, baz : 7 }
  }
, {
     foo : { bar : 1, baz : 2 }
  ,  bar : { bar : 2, baz : 7 }
  } ]
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this has to do with the way that V8 uses "hidden classes" to represent similar objects, but what you are reporting seems to be a pretty dramatic difference in footprints...

You can read more about hidden classes here: https://developers.google.com/v8/design
although that article seems to be more focused on speed than memory usage.